# When using Visual Studio custom templates with parameters, how can you get the actual root namespace?

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I am attempting to set up a template to create a unit test class with some basic structure and default using statements. I have created a VS2010 custom template to do this and almost everything works correctly.

The issue I have encountered is that I am attempting to reference my project's base namespace in my using statements, and am unable to determine whether there is a parameter that will let me do this.

An example of what I want, assuming my project is called MyProduct.Test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using MyProduct.Test.Base;

namespace MyProduct.Test.BLL.Services.MyService
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyServiceTest : TestBase
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        etc...
```

I can generate everything except for `using MyProduct.Test.Base` with the template below:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using $safeprojectname$.Base;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class $safeitemname$ : TestBase
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        etc...
```

Unfortunately, $safeprojectname$ is only available for Project templates, not Item templates.

This template results in the following output:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using $safeprojectname$.Base;

namespace MyProduct.Test.BLL.Services.MyService
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyServiceTest : TestBase
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        etc...
```

Is there any way for me to get the *actual* root namespace of my project (since $rootnamespace$ actually outputs the namespace for the file being added based on its location)?

Note: Obviously I can set this up to work fine for one project, but it would be much more useful to have a template that works for all projects.